# Given the group $G$ and $h,g \in G$ prove that $|gh|=|hg|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Sorry if this is an evident question but I don't know how to start answering it. If the group $G$ is abelian then both elements $hg$ and $gh$ are the same, so its order is evidently equal. But if commutativity is not a given, how can one state that two different elements would always have the same order? Is there some "ordinary" group property that I am missing? Or should another property about $G$ be stated (finite, normal, state precisely its generators etc.)? Any insight would be very much appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3741886/how-do-two-conjugate-elements-of-a-group-have-the-same-order

Comment: Indeed, $gh$ and $hg$ are conjugate in $G$, so they have the same order. This has been proved here already in several duplicates.

Comment: To see that they are conjugate, note that $(ghg)^{-1}gh(ghg)=hg$

Comment: @Randall Or just $g^{-1}(gh)g=hg$.

Comment: Yikes, right.  Much simpler.